# Winapi radio button bevahivour

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, atl, wtl

I have created a custom image drawing checkbox in WTL and I am now trying to create a custom image drawn radio button, how does the radio button work, when a user cliks one button to select it how does the other buttons get unselected? Do they receive a predefined window message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read about WS_GROUP, WS_TABSTOP

Comment: @PaulStock:  I think - should not, "sapienti sat".